# rvest dowload fig from web xpath while chrome inspected not worked, why this in head of xml document will worked?

Tags: r

I wanna to download an image from url:
[target fig link xpath in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLyWO.jpg)
https://tophatter.com/lots/104461372

to extract :

https://images.tophatter.com/42c09f609e7a6a47c70e0e1ccf3a0bb6/large.jpg

> while the xpath not worked: div[class='col-md-7 slot-images']  img
>
> in Chrome browser >  inspection > click the large fig, the Xpath shown in :
> //*[@id="lot-modal-content"]/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLyWO.jpg)/img

it`s in xml body part, not worked in rvest tutorial

```
library(rvest)
library(downloader)
library(dplyr)

url <- "https://tophatter.com/lots/104461372"
doc <- read_html(url)
doc <- xml2::read_html(url)

doc %>% html_nodes("div.col-md-7") %>% html_attr("class")
doc %>% html_nodes("div.col-md-7") %>% html_attr("src")
```

below is return
'col-md-7 slot-images'
NA

Comment: the target picture were in this link:http://snpy.in/Kiptyp

Answer (score 0):

here my solution ,after trail and error,i found the target jpg url in head part

```
a = doc %>% html_nodes("meta") %>% html_attrs
a = doc %>% html_nodes("meta") %>% html_attr("content") %>% na.omit
index = a %>% stringr::str_detect(".jpg") %>% which
a[index]
```

[result screen shotcut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anUv6.png)